# Loop not pushing game data to Array before console dump?

Tags: javascript

I have been looking over this code and redoing it so often trying to get this loop to work. I have also come to realise i am getting 429 error from s3 which i have to look into to. in the matter at hand, i am attempting to save the data to my gameData Array and then output via console after the promise has fulfilled so ultimately the promise variable can return the array. But i am not able to get all the data to store in the array. Something todo with the loop i guess but i cant pin point it. Any ideas?

```
var getGameData = function(matchIdArray) {
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
  s3.headObject({Bucket: 'lolsearchgames', Key: '347341'}, function(err, result) {
    if (err && err.code === 'NotFound') {
      var gameData = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < matchIdArray.length; i++) {
        gameData.push(new Promise(function(res, rej) { lolapi.Match.get(matchIdArray[i], function (error, gamedata) {
            if (error) {
                rej(error);
            }
            if (gamedata) {
                res(gamedata);
            }
        })})
        .then(function() {
          if (i === 9) {
            console.log(gameData);
            resolve(gameData);
          }
        }));
      }
    } else {
      // Retrieve from s3 Bucket
    }
  })
});
return promise;
};
```

Comment: `But i am not able to get all the data to store in the array` - is the array "short" of what you expect, or is the data in the array items just not what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of your code that needs to be rewritten

```
if (err && err.code === 'NotFound') {
    var gameData = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < matchIdArray.length; i++) {
        gameData.push(new Promise(function(res, rej) {
                lolapi.Match.get(matchIdArray[i], function(error, gamedata) {
                    if (error) {
                        rej(error);
                    }
                    if (gamedata) {
                        res(gamedata);
                    }
                })
            })
        );
    }
    Promise.all(gamedata).then(function() {
        console.log(gameData);
        resolve(gameData);
    });
}
```

This uses Promise.all on the array of gamedata promises to wait for them to all resolve before resolving the "main" promise

Note: this is a quick and dirty fix, the code may be able to be rewritten to remove the need for the outer `new Promise` - however, without seeing the code foe the `else` that's only a speculation on my part

Still "quick and dirty", but a better rewrite

```
if (err && err.code === 'NotFound') {
    Promise.all(matchIdArray.map(function(matchId) {
        return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
            lolapi.Match.get(matchId, function(error, gamedata) {
                if (error) {
                    rej(error);
                }
                if (gamedata) {
                    res(gamedata);
                }
            })
        });
    })).then(function() {
        console.log(gameData);
        resolve(gameData);
    });
}
```